# How to detect a body between two points on LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, jbox2d

[image]

I've two Vector2 (A and B), i draw a line between them.

Is there a way to check if the line intersect the Box2D CircleShape?
I need to a boolean output

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `World#rayCast(callback, fromPoint, toPoint)` to raycast the line.

```
callback = new RayCastCallback() {
    @Override
    public float reportRayFixture(Fixture fixture, Vector2 point, Vector2 normal, float fraction) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
};
world.rayCast(callback, point1, point2);
```